# how to move cursor between viewports while extruding

Tags: mesh, extrude

I'm following the "04 Nose Blocking" tutorial movie under "Learning Character Modeling" at cloud.blender.org. (particularly at time marker -2:11)

In this episode, the light-speed fast tutor manages to extrude the nose ridge in two different directions (x,y) *in the same extrusion move*.

It seems like the tutor is hopping with the cursor, dragging the extrusion, between two vies, front and right.

How is that done?
(I'm not referring to the 3Dcursor, just the little "+", controlling the actual dragging motion, connected to my mouse directly.)

Comment: I think you are expecting something unreal, Mirror Modifier can do it better for what you are expecting.

Comment: Anyways if you got your answer, try answering it in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply! Well, it seems like I was fooled by the hidden efficiency of Blender: When I finish an extrude (left click), the new edge is still marked, so just scooting over to another viewport and pressing G will just shuffle that new edge around in another direction, like the extrude continued there. I totally missed out that the newly created edge is as movable as any other selected part. (Old Solid CAD modeller here, hard to get used to this...)